# atomic question from core java

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic

This is a section from Core Java 8th edition Page 757

CAUTION:

```
public void flipDone() {
   done = !done;
}
```

// not atomic

I don't understand why it's not atomic. Can any one tell me why? thanks

Comment: Read about java memory model here: http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/java-memory-model.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `flipDone` method is executed by the computer in three distinct steps:

```
Read the value of memory location labeled done into ALU
Flip the value (i.e true -> false or false -> true)
Write the new value into the memory location done
```

In Java, a piece of code can potentially be invoked in multiple threads. These threads should be thought of as executing the code *concurrently*.

Say, memory location labeled `done` contains the value `false` initially. Consider two threads calling `flipDone`, resulting in the following sequence of steps:

```
Thread 1                             Thread 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Read value of done, false
Invert that value to true
Write the new value, true, to done       
                                     Read value of done, now true
                                     Invert that value to false
                                     Write the new value, false, to done
```

The `flipDone` method was called twice. `done` went from `false` to `true` and then back again to `false` - as one would expect. But since the threads execute concurrently, this is not the only ordering of steps. Consider this ordering instead:

```
Thread 1                             Thread 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
Read value of done, false
Invert that value to true            Read value of done, false
Write the new value, true, to done   Invert that value to true    
                                     Write the new value, true, to done
```

While the first thread is inverting the value it read, the second thread, concurrently, is reading the value. Similarly, while the first thread is writing the value to memory, the second thread is inverting the value *it read*. When `Thread 2` finishes, the value of `done` will be true. Here, although `flipDone` was called twice, `done` was flipped only once! One of the updates seem to have been *lost*. This is the problem that the book is trying to warn you about.

Answer (score 6):

There are three steps here:

1. Read the value of the boolean `done`
2. Invert the value read in step 1
3. Assign that value to the boolean `done`

There's nothing to stop another thread from pre-empting in the middle of all this.

Answer (score 4):

Because two threads may be calling `flipDone()` method at the same time so the state of the `done` variable is indeterminate.

Answer (score 4):

When you execute

```
done = !done;
```

What actually happens is:

```
1. Get the value of done
2. Apply the not operator
3. Assign it to done
```

If two threads execute the first step together, they are going to have the same value of done, so instead of changing it two times, they will change it only once.

For instance if done was initially true, after changing it two times you'd expect it's still true, but if the two threads execute step 1 together, it will be false.

Answer (score 0):

It does not execute as a single indivisible operation but instead is a sequence of three discrete operations - Fetch the current value of done, Negate the value, Write the new value back to done. It is a `read-modify-write` operation in which the resulting state is derived from the previous state.